# Deleting backup copy of file after the original has been deleted

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have original files on one drive (J:), and run a windows 10 batch file to make a backup copy on another drive (K:). I use this command and it works great:

```
xcopy "J:\files" "K:\files" /d /e /f /i /v
```

It creates new subdirectories and does not care about the file name at all.

Now my problem is that sometimes a file from the original location on J: gets deleted and the backup copy on K: is still there taking up space when I no longer need it.

I probably need to loop through all of the files in the backup K: directory and sub directories and delete the files which can not be found in the same path on original J: location. I have tried searching StackOverflow and have found nothing close to this other than looping files in a directory. I am probably using the wrong search terms, but this seems like a common problem which should already have a solution around here somewhere.

Any help pointing me to an existing post about this, or a suggestion for what code to use would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please open a Command Prompt window, type, or paste: `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key to find out how to use the command line utility which superseded `xcopy.exe` over fourteen years ago. It has options to directly perform the exact task you have described.

Comment: [Windows cmd is very different from DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). Don't call cmd DOS

Comment: Thanks @Compo for pointing me in the right direction. The _robocopy.exe_ command is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking (delete files in destination that are not present in source), is called "mirroring".

xcopy doesn't support mirroring.

A **workaround** is this:

You can run `xcopy "K:\files" "J:\files" /L > filestodelete.txt` (I have reversed the destination and the source) to obtain a list of files which exist in the destination folder but not in source folder. Then you can use a for loop to delete those files in the destination folder.

You have to consider that xcopy is no longer used anymore. It has been replaces by `robocopy` which use the same options as xcopy but has a lot more funtionality. For example, the parameter `/MIR` is used to mirror one folder to the other. As a bonus, robocopy is way faster.

`/MIR` parameter includes `/PURGE` parameter, which deletes dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.

The syntax for the "robocopy" version, is the following:

```
xcopy "J:\files" "K:\files" /MIR
```

Answer (score 0):

The robocopy.exe with the mirror option makes an exact copy of the directory.

```
robocopy J:\files K:\files /mir
```